# How to access a WCF service from another solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, silverlight

Right now I have a utility built in Silverlight which uses a WCF service, and both of these projects are in the same solution.  Due to company standards, I have to put the WCF service into its own solution.  How do I access it from my Silverlight project from a seperate solution?  Everything I've found talks about how to access a WCF service from the same solution.  Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access on a WCF service from another solution, you have to :

- On your actual project, right click on the WCF Service > View in browser (I suppose the WCF Service is hosted on IIS).
- Copy the URL (it will be a URL like `http://localhost:12345/MyWCFService.svc`)
- On your new project, right click on the project > Add Service Reference
- Paste the URL

Hope it helps

Comment: Ahh I see.  I had actually tried something similar, but I also ended up subtley renaming the service, so I had to change those references too.  Thanks!